# Javascript having 'fetch' not working on Android 5.1.1

Tags: javascript, android, webview, fetch-api

I have a page opened via WebView in Android.
It contains fetch promise for downloading some data.
It's working on all device, but not on Android 5.1.1.
I have updated Google Play Services and WebView on 5.1.1 device, but still it's not recognizing fetch command and also 'let' and 'const' keywords.

Comment: I don't know what browser WebView uses, but according to CanIUse there are still some browsers that have not implemented the fetch() method (https://caniuse.com/#search=fetch). So maybe it's using one of those browsers.

Answer (score 1):

it won't work, window.fetch or fetch is a new API introduced by browsers to simplify XHR, you can track implementation of fetch by various browsers here https://caniuse.com/#feat=fetch

if you still want to use fetch you can use a polyfill for fetch
https://github.com/github/fetch